java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.dozer.factory.DestBeanCreator
I'm getting this below error in one of the flows of my application running in WAS.
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.dozer.factory.DestBeanCreator (initialization failure)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:86) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:52) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:41) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1641) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1532) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277) ~[cxf-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

The dozer jar version 5.3.2 is available in WEB-INF/lib.
Any leads would be helpful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

From this old question: "Search your logs for errors that include "Reason." in the stack trace to find the underlying cause."
